# Libreoffice SDK

Tags: libreoffice, sdk

Please anyone help me to install and correctly configure libreoffice sdk in Ubuntu 13.04.
I have installed sdk using `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-dev`

and then configured it by `/usr/lib/libreoffice/sdk/setsdkenv_unix.sh` and got following output :-

```
SDK environment is prepared for Linux
SDK = /usr/lib/libreoffice/sdk
Office = /usr/lib/libreoffice
URE = /usr/lib/libreoffice/ure-link
Make = /usr/bin
Zip = /usr/bin
C++ Compiler = /usr/bin
Java = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
SDK Output directory = /home/dawnavd/openoffice.org4.1_sdk
Auto deployment = NO
```

but still I'm not able to run this [c++ example](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/cpp/DocumentLoader/)

Please help me and tell what else need to be done.

Following are details of error I'm getting while running this c++ example
I first run this:`make -f Makefile.txt`
and then I got following output and error message :-

```
    mkdir -p Desktop/GSoC/libreoffice4.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/misc
    rm -f Desktop/GSoC/libreoffice4.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/misc/oosdk_cpp_types.flag
    "/usr/lib/libreoffice/sdk/bin/cppumaker" -Gc -      ODesktop/GSoC/libreoffice4.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/inc "/usr/lib/libreoffice/ure-link/share/misc/types.rdb" "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/types/offapi.rdb"  
    ERROR: cannot open  for writing
    make: ***  [Desktop/GSoC/libreoffice4.1_sdk/LINUXexample.out/misc/oosdk_cpp_types.flag] Error 1
```

Comment: Why are you not able to run this example? Do you encouter an error? Please specify what all you have done and what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you should be able to install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-dev*
```

To quote [Synaptic Package Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/):

> ### office productivity suite -- SDK
>
> LibreOffice is a full-featured office productivity suite that provides a
> near drop-in replacement for Microsoft(R) Office.
> This package contains the files needed to build plugins/add-ons for
> LibreOffice (includes, IDL files, build tools, ...). It also contains
> the zipped source of the UNO Java libraries for use in IDEs like
> eclipse.

Also, I would recommend updating soon from 13.04, as it is [now End Of Life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). It should [be simple to Upgrade it](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade).